# SPLIT_BUNDLE 4: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section:

Tags: google-play-console

SPLIT_BUNDLE 4: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)
I tried all the options like belowbut it didnt work.
Open Google Play Console

App content

Data safety => Manage

Overview click next

Answer the questions (then next):

Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? = yes

Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? = yes

Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted? = yes

go to Device or other IDs and check it then next

check Device or other IDs and manage it

answer the questions:

Is this data collected, shared, or both? = Collected

Is this data processed ephemerally? = yes

Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected? = Users can choose whether this data is collected

Why is this user data collected? = check App functionality

then save

click next and save and app will review and approved by play store team

This also not working...

Let me know for any comments.

Tried the above said option but its not working. So need a solution to solve the issue.
We are getting the below details with location.
name,
email,
phone number,
gender,
image,
password

Answer (score 0):

@NextV Zyiper

As per the new user data policy, it is mandatory to provide an account deletion web link, Are you sure you are providing it?

Kindly refer to this link
[https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13327111#zippy=%2Cam-i-required-to-fill-out-account-deletion-questions-within-the-data-safety-form-in-play-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBLEd.png)

[image]

Comment: We have already provided the link for deletion but it still showing the same. Thanks for your response.